# (Ajax) Authenticate MVC Website user using a WebAPI

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Trying to search for this results many many results for securing a WebAPI and how to secure an MVC application, but i could not find a solution.

What i want to achieve:
i have an MVC website with a modal Login form,
When the user enters he's credentials to the the form, an Ajax request is sent to a WebAPI with the credentials.
The WebAPI should return (i guess a ticket, since that is what i found).
The ticket would be then saved into the sessionStorage of the browser (no cookies),
Each page request to the website will check for the token, and enable/disable the parts that need to be secured.

All the examples i have found are showing either MVC only authentication,
or WebAPI authentication, but i could not find anything that does the described above.

Answer (score 0):

The sessionStorage is available only for client-side use. You can manipulate or retrieve values from the storage using Javascript, but you can't directly read data from the server. Since MVC typically renders HTML Views server side, you have no options to send the token stored in the sessionStorage on each request.

The situation you described is an hybrid solution which can't be achieved without the use of cookies.

A simple solution is to set the login data (specifically the token if you will use a token-based approach) in a cookie issued by the Web API endpoint during the login phase.

Comment: What? i think you miss understood what i am asking for...
Please try reading the question again.
I am well aware to the technologies involved.
Why would i save the data to a cookie and not to sessionStorage?
What would limit me to read the token from sessionStorage and send it on a request? What would be the difference between a cookie being sent and a token?

Comment: also, how would you store a cookie that is generated by the WebAPI in an Ajax request? And if you already did that, Why do you need a cookie and not a token?

Comment: The fact is that a cookie will be automatically sent by the browser to the server on each requests. If you store the token in the sessionStorage you can access to its content using javascript, which is perfectly Ok if you will execute further request using AJAX, but not if you use some kind of server-side framework like MVC. You can't send the token inside an header if you click a link inside the webpage.

Comment: pretty sure i wrote AJAX in the title.
By replying to you, i actually think i have an idea on how to it.
When the link is clicked, a Query parameter can send the Token, The page will verify the token and display a Login/Register page if the token is invalid, or just show the page if the token is valid.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused now. You talked about an AJAX request for the authentication process, but then you say that each *page* request will check the token, so I assumed that the AJAX request was just the first one (with the credentials).

Comment: Also, be aware of the [possible security pitfalls](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string) from the use of token in query string.